# Is there any way to get a class for or instantiate a doubly-generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics, factory-pattern, nested-generics

So say I have:

```
public class Foo<T> {
  // Some stuff
}

public interface Factory<T> {
  T newInstance();
  Class<T> getKlass();
}
```

And I want to make an implementation of Factory to build Foo<T>s:

```
public class FooFactory<T> implements Factor<Foo<T>> {
  private Class<Foo<T>> klass;
  public FooFactory(Class<Foo<T>> klass) {
    this.klass = klass;
  }

  public T newInstance() throws Exception {
    return klass.newInstance();
  }

  public Class<Foo<T>> getKlass() {
    return klass;
  }
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is there any way for me to get a Class<Foo<T>> if all I have is Class<T>? Unfortunately Foo is a private class, and therefore the only code that has the whole picture (i.e., knowledge of what T will be) can't know about Foo and therefore can't give me Class<Foo<T>>.
2. Is there a better way I could be going about this?

Thanks!

P.S. For those asking for more detail, here we go. The full story is that Foo and FooFactory will both be private classes in an outer class. Foo is used extensively throughout the outer class, and to avoid spurious garbage collection, I'd like to use an ObjectPool to instantiate instances of Foo rather than newing them up and having them garbage collected all the time. However, in order to use my ObjectPool, I need a Factory<Foo<T>>, and inside of Outer<T> I obviously can't know what T will be when Outer<T> is instantiated.

```
public class Outer<T> {
  private class Foo<T> { ... }
  private class FooFactory<T> {...}

  private ObjectPool<Foo<T>> fooPool;

  ...
}
```

Comment: your code example above does not illustrate what you are trying to do.  You say Foo is private but don't provide the outer class

Comment: Added a postscript with more explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested generic in a generic class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452158/nested-generic-in-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to create a the type information for `Class<Foo<T>>` but to do what you want, you simply need to suppress all generics warnings in `FooFactory`.

At runtime, Java uses `Object` in all places where you wrote `T`, so you can simply instantiate `Foo<Object>` or `Foo.class`, they are the same. This is called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Generics are just a hint for the compiler. Since your API makes sure that all code using `FooFactory` will honor the type `T`, you can suppress the warnings and use the appropriate casts and it will work.

Note: If you want to preserve type information, implement [the `ParameterizedType` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html).

Comment: This works for the newInstance() method, but won't help me for the getKlass() method. The compiler won't allow a cast from Class<Foo> to Class<Foo<T>>, which is the required return type.

Comment: I think OP and the community would be better served if you could explain why 1) it is good idea to ignore the warning and 2) why the warning is generated in the first place.  I bring this up because I see people constantly squelching warnings, they are there for a very specific reason.

Comment: @honktronic: Try `return (Class)klass;` and suppress the `rawtypes` warning.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I agree with you but not in this instance. The warnings are generated because OP needs to violate generics rules in the code and the reason why he has to suppress them is that Java doesn't offer a way to achieve what he wants without breaking the rules.

Comment: For reference, it's not quite true in general that Java uses `Object` in all places where you wrote `T`.  For example, if you have the context `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, then Java will substitute `Comparable`, not `Object`, for `T`.

Answer (score 0):

There is just one `Foo` class object, which is equal to `Foo.class`. Although you can write `Class<Foo<whatever>>`, that is kind of deceptive since it is all the same `Foo` class object. Of course, you need `Class<Foo<T>>` to be able to call `newInstance()` and get a `Foo<T>`. So to get around the fact that you need a `Class<Foo<T>>` and that `Foo.class` has type `Class<Foo>`, you just do some casting:

```
public FooFactory() {
  this.klass = (Class<Foo<T>>)(Class<?>)Foo.class;
}
```

Note that we don't need `Class<T>` at all, because you don't need to know `T` to create a `Foo<T>`.